# Identifying a process that leaks memory

Tags: linux, memory, swap, debug

On a linux server (Ubuntu Lucid), my used swap keeps growing by the hour on a server, and I'm having a hard time identifying which process is growing in swap.

What tool can I use to monitor this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The usual way I do this is to let the system run until the swap utilization is evidently higher than it "should" be.  Once you can see the problem run `top`, sort by Virtual Memory Size (sometimes just called `Size`, or `VIRT` on Linux -- The guy with the largest difference between VM Size and Resident size (`RES`) is usually your culprit.

The best way to know for sure is to make sure it's safe and then kill the process - If your swap suddenly frees up you found your leak.

Comment: Looking at the diff between resident memory and VM size is a good hint. Thanks.

Comment: It's about 90% reliable -- I've found very few programs that allocate gobs of RAM and intentionally let it go stale enough that it gets swapped out :)

Comment: As a note, `<` and `>` can be used to select the column to sort by.

Comment: Didn't know about `<` and `>` (Apparently doesn't work on FreeBSD 8's `top` though - you have to use `o` to set the sort order there)

Answer (score 2):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131303/linux-how-to-measure-actual-memory-usage-of-an-application-or-process

Should help you out. :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running `top` and pressing `M` to sort all processes by memory usage?